# How do I parse JSON output from Google Maps API v3 distance matrix to PHP?

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

I just want to get the output from Google Maps API Distance Matrix into PHP for further processing. I can’t figure out how to get the distance value back into a variable. My data is [a JSON file from Google’s Maps API v3](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false).

```json
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "San Francisco, Californie, États-Unis", "Victoria, BC, Canada" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Vancouver, BC, Canada", "Seattle, Washington, États-Unis" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1 703 km",
                  "value" : 1703343
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 jours 19 heures",
                  "value" : 326836
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "138 km",
                  "value" : 138267
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "6 heures 45 minutes",
                  "value" : 24278
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1 451 km",
                  "value" : 1451182
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 jours 4 heures",
                  "value" : 274967
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "146 km",
                  "value" : 146496
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 heures 52 minutes",
                  "value" : 10321
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I’m new to javascript and JSON with minimal PHP experience.

Answer (score 8):

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false';
$json = file_get_contents($url); // get the data from Google Maps API
$result = json_decode($json, true); // convert it from JSON to php array
echo $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make sure you separate places with + not a space in the url:

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Place+City&destinations=Place+City';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch))
    {
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
    }
    else{
        echo json_decode($response,true);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Hyderabad+Telangana+India&destinations=Mumbai+Maharashtra+India';
$json = file_get_contents($url); 
$result = json_decode($json, true);
$mi = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
$km = $mi*1.60934;
echo round($km)." KM <br/>";
echo $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
```